# How can I sort Labels in config entity list builder?

Tags: 8

I have a very simple config entity with a few fields. In the list builder I want to sort the `label` field by creation date rather than by alphabetical order.

I originally thought this should be fairly easy, but it's proving way more difficult than I expected.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question I guess.

Config entities list builder extends the `ConfigEntityListBuilder` class,
which comes with a few built in methods, among which

```
  /**
   * Loads entity IDs using a pager sorted by the entity id.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An array of entity IDs.
   */
  protected function getEntityIds() {
    $query = $this->getStorage()->getQuery()
      ->sort($this->entityType->getKey('id'));

    // Only add the pager if a limit is specified.
    if ($this->limit) {
      $query->pager($this->limit);
    }
    return $query->execute();
  }
```

To sort, in whichever you ones desires, the display list itself all that needs to be done is overwrite the function in the child class.

In my case it was something like this:

```
protected function getEntityIds() {
  $query = $this
    ->getStorage()
    ->getQuery()
    ->sort('notification_creation_date', 'DESC');

  // Only add the pager if a limit is specified.
  if ($this->limit) {
    $query->pager($this->limit);
  }
  return $query->execute();
}
```